# XCode 11.5 Nested Dictionaries

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I am working on converting my python 3.8 code over to XCode 11.5 and I am struggling to understand XCode nested dictionaries.  My data file is one big dictionary in Python.  I have been scouring the web looking for examples, documentation, and code to understand how I can get this to port over to XCode.

Here's an example of my python dictionary structure:

```
/*
myDict definition in python:

{
    {'data0': {
                <strd0i1> : <str>
                <strd0i2> : <boolean>
                <strd0i3> : <int>
                <strd0i4> : <int>
              }
    }
    {'data1': 
              {
                <strd1> :
                {
                   <strd1i1> : { <int> : <int> }
                }
                {   
                   <strd1i2> : { <int> : <int> }
                }
                {   
                   <strd1i3> : <array[int]>
                }
                {   
                   <strd1i4> : 
                   { 
                     <strd1i4-1> : <array[int]>
                     <strd1i4-2> : <str>
                     <int>  : {
                                <str1> : <int>
                                <str2> : <str>
                                <str3> : <int>
                              }
                   }
                }
                {  
                   <strd1i5> : <array(int)>
                }
                {  <strd1i6>: 
                   {
                     <strd1i6-1> : <int>
                   }
                }
              }
    }
    {'data2':  {
                 <strd2> : <array(int)>
               }
    }
    {'data3':   <strd3> : <int>
    }
}
*/
myDict = {}
myDict['data0'] = {}
myDict['data0']['strd0i1'] = 'abc'
mydict['data0']['strd0i2'] = true
mydict['data0']['strd0i3'] = 25
mydict['data0']['strd0i4'] = 16
myDict['data1'] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1'] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i1'] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i1'][93] = 35
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i1'][32] = 5
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i2'] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i2'][17] = 45
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i2'][45] = 17
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i3'] = [15,32,8,45,17]
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4'] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4']['strd1i4-1'] = [34,12,72,34]
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4']['strd1i4-2'] = 'def'
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4'][15] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4'][15]['str1'] = 27
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4'][15]['str2'] = 'ghi'
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i4'][15]['str3'] = 42
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i5'] = [24,32,16,71,52]
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i6'] = {}
myDict['data1']['strd1']['strd1i6']['strd1i6-1'] = 12
myDict['data2'] = {}
myDict['data2']['strd2'] = [32,65,41,71,65]
myDict['data3'] = {}
myDict['data3']['strd3'] = 33

print (myDict)
```

I read where XCode prefers the use of structures.  However, I have not had any success trying to build a multilevel/dimensional structure either:

```
struct myDict {
    struct data0 {
        var strd0i1:String
        var strd0i2:Bool
        var strd0i3:Int
        var strd0i4:Int
    }
    struct data1:Array {
        struct strd1:Array {
            var strd1Name:String // [def, mno]
            struct strd1i1:Array { // defi1
                var strd1i1Num:Int
                var strd1i1ID:Int
            }
            struct strd1i2:Array { // defi2
                var strd1i2Num:Int
                var strd1i2ID:Int
            }
            var strd1i3:Array<Int>
            struct strd1i4 {
                var strd1i4_1:Array<Int>
                var strd1i4_2:String
                var strd1i4_3:Struct<Int> {
                    var str1:Int
                    var str2:String
                    var str3:Int
                }
            }
            var strd1i5:Array<Int>
            struct strd1i6 {
                var strd1i6Num:String
                var strd1i6ID:Int
            }
        }
    }
    struct data2 { // patterns
        var strd2Name:String
        var strd2Nums:Array<Int>
    }
    struct data3 {
        var data3ID:String
        var data3Num:Int
    }
}
myDict.data0.init(strd0i1: "abc", strd0i2: true, strd0i3: 25, strd0i4: 16)
myDict.data1.strd1.init(strd1Name: "def", strd1i3: [15,32,8,45,17], strd1i5: [24,32,16,71,52])
myDict.data1.strd1.strd1i1.init(strd1i1Num: 93, strd1i1ID: 32)
myDict.data1.strd1.strd1i1.93 = 35
myDict.data1.strd1.strd1i1.32 = 55987
myDict.data1.strd1.strd1i2.init(strd1i2Num: 17, strd1i2ID: 45)
myDict.data1.strd1.strd1i2.17 = 45
myDict.data1.strd1.strd1i2.45 = 17

print(myDict)
print (myDict.data0.strd0i1)
```

I even tried declaring the dictionary, but it appears I don't have a clue what I am doing.

```
var myDict:Dictionary = {String:{String:, String:, Bool:, Int:, Int:}{String:{Array:{String:{Int:Int}}}{String:{Int:Int}String:Array}{String:{String:Array, String:String{Int:, String:, Int:}}}{String:Array}{String:{String:Int}}}}{String:String:Array}{String:{Int:Int}}

print (myDict)
```

Like I wrote above, I have been scouring the documentation and the web for clear examples.  I'm sure I'm not inventing the wheel here.

**EDIT:**
Okay, so I've tried a few different things and still not grasping this structure vs. dictionary concept.

Here's another example of what I'm trying to do:

```
struct Settings {
    var debug = false
    var bgColor = 0
    var printerName = "default"
}

struct Client {
    var dlNumber:String // Format will be two character state followed by number)
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String
    var address1:String
    var address2:String
    var city:String
    var state:String
    var postalCode:String
    var itemRented:Int
    var timeOut:Date
    var timeIn:Date
}

struct Condition {
    var condition = ["New", "Like New", "Great", "Good", "Worn", "Fair", "Poor"]
}

struct Service {
    var date:Date
    var workPerformed:String
    var notes:String
}

struct RentalInfo {
    var date:Date
    var client:Client
    var problem:Bool
    var note:String
}

struct Bicycle {
    var itemNum:Int
    var make:String
    var model:String
    var color:Int
    var year:Int
    var timesRented:Int
    var hoursUsed:Int
    var condition:Condition
    var serviceHistory:[Service]
    var rentalHistory:[RentalInfo]
}

struct Scooter {
    var itemNum:Int
    var make:String
    var model:String
    var color:Int
    var year:Int
    var timesRented:Int
    var hoursUsed:Int
    var condition:Condition
    var serviceHistory:[Service]
    var rentalHistory:[RentalInfo]
}

struct MyDict {
    var settings:Settings
    var client:[Client]
    var bicycles:[Bicycle]
    var scooters:[Scooter]
}

var myDict:MyDict

myDict.settings.debug = true
myDict.settings.bgColor = 3
myDict.settings.printerName = "Invoices"

print(myDict.settings)

myDict.client.append(dlNumber:"AL123456", firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", address1:"123 Main Street", address2:"", city:"Somewhere", state:"AL", postalCode:"12345", itemRented:0, timeOut:"2020-06-14 19:41:00 +0000", timeIn:"")

print(myDict.client)
```

This is the error xcode produces in my playground:

```
error: Structures.xcplaygroundpage:89:21: error: extra arguments at positions #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11 in call
myDict.client.append(dlNumber:"AL123456", firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", address1:"123 Main Street", address2:"", city:"Somewhere", state:"AL", postalCode:"12345", itemRented:0, timeOut:"2020-06-14 19:41:00 +0000", timeIn:"")
                    ^

error: Structures.xcplaygroundpage:89:31: error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Client'
myDict.client.append(dlNumber:"AL123456", firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", address1:"123 Main Street", address2:"", city:"Somewhere", state:"AL", postalCode:"12345", itemRented:0, timeOut:"2020-06-14 19:41:00 +0000", timeIn:"")
                              ^
```

Comment: Note that it is Swift naming convention to name your types starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: Can you post a JSON string? It would be much easier to structure it.

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks.  I will work on fixing that.

Comment: Also, I am not using any JSON.  I created my dictionary and then I add to it.  It is one big data file and I reference its properties through my application.

Comment: So what you are looking for is a dictionary of dictionaries `var dict:[String: [String: Any]] = [:]` but it will be a pain to deal with it

Comment: So dictionaries are not as simple to work with in XCode as they are in Python?  I've been studying up some more on structures.  That may be the route I need to go since that is what XCode prefers one to use.

Comment: The problem is not the dictionary itself but the Any type. You would need to cast from Any to dictionary or other types to access its descendants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with Structs, but it looks like you're trying to define them at the point of variable declaration. What you want to do is define a type for each member of your data and then compose those types.

For example you would define struct `data0` (I would advise digging into naming conventions, as Swift types are usually WrittenLikeThis):

```
struct data0 {
    var strd0i1: String
    var strd0i2: Bool
    var strd0i3: Int
    var strd0i4: Int
}
```

and then a type `myDict` would have members of the previously defined types (again naming):

```
struct myDict {
    var data0: data0 //The type you defined above
    // ... The rest of the data structure with other types.
}
```

With the dictionaries you're defining in Python you have key-value pairs without a rigid structure and with values of any type. With Swift objects you are defining what members each object has and the type of their members. Once you've defined the shape of your models, you'll then create instances of theses models.

In your latest example the models seem to be set up properly, but you aren't creating new instances of you objects before adding them. The append method on the client array expects an argument of type `Client`:

```
let newClient = Client(dlNumber:"AL123456", firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", address1:"123 Main Street", address2:"", city:"Somewhere", state:"AL", postalCode:"12345", itemRented:0, timeOut:"2020-06-14 19:41:00 +0000", timeIn:"")
myDict.client.append(newClient)
```

[This reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) on structs and classes could help you more generally.

Comment: So, I would create the Data0, Data1, Data2, and Data3 as separate structures, then combine them into one structure as MyDict?  If that is the case, would I further create smaller structures for the contents of Data1, etc.?

Comment: I still have questions.  Should I add to this one or create another question?

Comment: If it's the same topic, feel free to add here, otherwise best to make a new question .

Comment: I went ahead and added another example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The issue I am having is understanding how the struct is stored within the dictionary to differentiate between bicycle1, bicycle2, etc when they are entered.  In Python the dictionary is extremely easy to understand and work with.  I'm trying to figure out how I can experience the same simplicity in Swift/XCode.

Comment: I added a fix with some more information. Swift is a strongly typed language where you are best served by dealing with strong-typed models, as opposed to the dynamic type system of Python. I think you'll find it's just a question of becoming comfortable. There are definitely advantages to having things strong-typed!

Comment: Thank you!  I also found another who helped me understand the struct and setting up my dictionary for use.  I'll answer this question as well so it may help others who stumble across this.

Answer (score 0):

**XCode 11.5/Swift 5.2 Answer**

After asking about this issue on a few other sites I wanted to post another answer for a working solution.

To begin with, dictionaries in XCode/Swift are not easy to grasp when moving from Python.  But it is able to be done with some simple structuring of the dtat before putting it all together.

The dictionary structure:

```
{
    2020: {
        "January": {
            1: {
                "day":"Wednesday",
                "event1": {
                    "description":"Colonoscopy",
                    "time":"8:00AM",
                    "duration":60,
                    "alert":true,
                    "location":"Bottoms up clinic, Southside",
                    "note":"Not looking forward to this."
                }
                "event2": {
                    "description":"EDG",
                    "time":"9:00AM",
                    "duration":45,
                    "alert":false,
                    "location":"Bottoms up clinic, Southside",
                    "note":"Hope they change tubes."
                }
            }
            2: {
                "day":"Thursday",
                "event1": {
                    "description":"Vasectomy",
                    "time":"8:00AM",
                    "duration":60,
                    "alert":true,
                    "location":"Quick snips",
                    "note":"This year sucks!"
                }
            }
            3: {
                "day":"Friday",
                "event1": {
                    "description":"Party up with friends",
                    "time":"9:00PM",
                    "duration":240,
                    "alert":true,
                    "location":"Marco's Pillow Bar",
                    "note":"Call ahead to reserve large pillows to sit on"
                }
            }
            4: {
                "day":"Saturday"
            }
            5: {
                "day":"Sunday"
            }
            6: {
                "day":"Monday"
            }
        }
        "February": {
            13: {
                "day":"Thursday"
            }
            14: {
                "day":"Friday",
                "event1": {
                    "description":"Call Gloria and tell her you're not feeling good.",
                    "time":"7:00AM",
                    "duration":5,
                    "alert":true,
                    "location":"",
                    "note":"Remember to sound really sick on the phone."
                }
                "event2": {
                    "description":"Boating with Billy and his lady friends from work."
                    "time":"8:00AM"
                    "duration":480
                    "alert":true
                    "location":"Tear Drop Lake"
                    "note":"Get beer, ice, and sunscreen.  And do not comment about Barbara's big nose."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code:

```
enum CalendarMonthName: Int {
    case january = 1, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december
}

typealias EventCalendar = [Int:CalendarYear]

struct CalendarYear {
    var months: [CalendarMonthName:CalendarMonth]
}

struct CalendarMonth {
    var days: [Int: CalendarDay]
}

struct CalendarDay {
    var day: String
    var events: [CalendarEvent]?
}

struct CalendarEvent {
    var description: String
    var time: String
    var duration: Int
    var alert: Bool
    var location: String
    var note: String
    var flags1: [Int]?
    var flags2: [String]?
}

var calendarOfEvents = EventCalendar()
calendarOfEvents[2020] = CalendarYear(months: [
    .january : CalendarMonth(days: [
        1: CalendarDay(day: "Wednesday", events: [
            CalendarEvent(description: "Colonoscopy", time: "8:00AM", duration: 60, alert: true, location: "Bottoms up clinic, Southside", note: "Not looking forward to this."),
            CalendarEvent(description: "EDG", time: "9:00AM", duration: 45, alert: false, location: "Bottoms up clinic, Southside", note: "Hope they change tubes.", flags1: [1,5,27])
        ]),
        2: CalendarDay(day: "Thursday", events: [
            CalendarEvent(description: "Vasectomy", time: "8:00AM", duration: 60, alert: true, location: "Quick Snips", note: "This year sucks!", flags2: ["Urgent", "Must Do"]),
        ]),
        3: CalendarDay(day: "Friday")
    ])
])
//print(calendarOfEvents[2020]?.months[.january]?.days[1]?.events?[0].description)
print(calendarOfEvents[2020]?.months[.january])
//print(calendarOfEvents)
print(type(of: EventCalendar.self))
```

Hope this helps someone.